# How do I add references for mdpi journal in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, mdpi

I want to add references in an article which I want to submit for mdpi. How can I add references?

Comment: The mdpi article template at overleaf shows two different ways to create a bibliography: "References, variant A: internal bibliography"  and "References, variant B: external bibliography".

Comment: Well how do begin? If I copied the BibTex and made a new file called references.bib how do I integrate it with my working .tex document?

Comment: As noted in the template, you type the name of your bibtex file in `\bibliography{your_external_BibTeX_file}`. Of course the bibtex file should also be uploaded on Overleaf (or created there).

Comment: @Marijn, I think Overleaf is encouriging the use of `biblatex` -- in which you use `\addbibresource{<filename>}`.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ Both bibtex and biblatex can be used on Overleaf; we don't advocate the use of one over another—it all depends on your needs (and the recommendations of the journal). As @leandriis pointed out, the MDPI journal shows two examples: using an internal bibliography or an external .bib file, with BibTeX. If you aren't familiar with BibTeX or citations in general, see e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX or https://www.overleaf.com/blog/532 or https://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies